# React Incremeting Counter Behind

Tags: reactjs

I've just learned to use `UseState` to create a simple incremental counter, but I've noticed some odd behavior with the count being 2 numbers behind (+ - ) in `console.log`. Now on the screen the number displays fine, but this creates an issue because I'm trying to change the color of the number if it's negative or positive.

Because I'm trying to change the display color of the number on the screen, would `UseEffect` be a good solution to this problem? I'm going to go back and watch some YT videos on UseEffect, but figured I'd ask here as well. I was thrilled when I was able to figure out how to change the classnames using state, but then got a pie in the face when the numbers weren't changing colors correctly.

Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/obthearchitect/pen/ZEWwNQJ?editors=0011) of the behavior I'm seeing.

```
const { useState } = React

function Vote () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [color, setColor] = useState('black')
  
  function handleDecrement () {
    setCount(count - 1)
    checkCount()
  }
  
 function handleIncrement () {
    setCount(count + 1)
    checkCount();
  }
  
  function checkCount () {
    // Less than 0 make it red
        if (count < 0) {
            setColor('red')
      console.log(count)
    // Greater than 1 make it green
        } else if (count > 0  ) {
            setColor('green')
      console.log(count)
    // If it's 0 just keep it black
        } else {
            setColor('black')
      console.log(count)
        }
    
  };
  
  return (
 <div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
      <h1 className={color}>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Vote />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use an effect hook with dependency to check the color. When `count` updates the effect hook callback is triggered.

The issue is that react state updates are asynchronous, so the updated state `count` won't be available until the *next* render cycle; you are simply using the `count` value from the *current* render cycle.

***Note:** When incrementing/decrementing counts you should use a functional state update. This ensures state is correctly updated from the previous state in the case multiple state updates are enqueued within any single render cycle.*

```
function Vote() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("black");

  function handleDecrement() {
    setCount(count => count - 1);
  }

  function handleIncrement() {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }

  useEffect(checkCount, [count]);

  function checkCount() {
    // Less than 0 make it red
    if (count < 0) {
      setColor("red");
      console.log(count);
      // Greater than 1 make it green
    } else if (count > 0) {
      setColor("green");
      console.log(count);
      // If it's 0 just keep it black
    } else {
      setColor("black");
      console.log(count);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
      <h1 className={color}>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-incremeting-counter-behind]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So if I understand useEffect correctly, it expects and Effect (e..g, Changing the colors) and it requires a dependency (e.g., the Count state). Why do we need to specify the dependency when it's called out in the effect? Ans lastly, why is it stored in an array [ ] brackets?

Comment: @RomeNYRR It is the syntax the effect expects so can specify when we want an effect's callback to be triggered. An effect with empty dependency array (`[]`) will only run once on component mount, and effect with populated dependency (`[dep1, dep2, dep3]`) will run ***only when*** one of the dependencies changes reference equality, and with no dependency array at all the effect will run on every render regardless.

Answer (score 1):

When updating the state based on the current state always use the callback version of `setState` which receives the current state as an argument and should return the next state. React batches state updates and [relying on what has been returned by `useState` to update can yield incorrect results](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value). Also the way to check for a change to `count` and update accordingly is by using `useEffect` with `count` as a dependency. The `console.log()` in your example will still log the old state as state updates are async and can only be seen during the next render.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const [color, setColor] = useState('black')

function handleDecrement () {
    setCount(current => current - 1);
}

function handleIncrement () {
    setCount(current => current + 1)
}

useEffect(() => {
    // Less than 0 make it red
    if (count < 0) {
        setColor('red')
        console.log(count)

    // Greater than 1 make it green
    } else if (count > 0  ) {
        setColor('green')
        console.log(count)

    // If it's 0 just keep it black
    } else {
        setColor('black')
        console.log(count)
    }

}, [count]);
```

Comment: A great and valid response. What's unclear to me is where current came came? Is that a keyword for managing state within react?

Comment: @RomeNYRR `current ` is the variable name provided to the state update callback function, it's a function parameter and can be named anything. The state hook passes the current state to this callback.